# ip/tcp payload compression using Zlib in C

Tags: c, tcp, compression, zlib, payload

I am trying to compress packet payload. I am reading a pcap file. But, after compression, most of the packets' sizes get increased. I am parsing payload length as source length and payload as in_data. Why does the compressed size get bigger?

I know that 6 bytes can be added, but some payloads having 1300 or 2300 bytes also increases the compressed size. If you look at the output you can see how compressed size gets increases.

The code is:

`````
#include <string.h>  // for strlen
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

#include <zlib.h>

#include "packet_structures.h"
#include "tls.h"
#include "ipzip_ipm.h"

void callback(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *pkthdr, const u_char *packet) {

    //printf("Packet size : %u \n", pkthdr->len);
    pq_ip_hdr* ip = (pq_ip_hdr*) (packet + sizeof (pq_eth_hdr));
    pq_tcp_hdr* tcp = (pq_tcp_hdr*) (packet + sizeof (pq_eth_hdr) + sizeof ( pq_ip_hdr));
    tls_Handshake_header* tls = (tls_Handshake_header*) (packet + sizeof (pq_eth_hdr) + sizeof ( pq_ip_hdr) + sizeof (pq_tcp_hdr));
    
    int ip_len, tcp_len;
    const u_char *payload;
    static int p_count = 1;
    
    ip_len = ip->hdr_len * 4;
    tcp_len = (((const u_char*) ip)[ip_len + 12] >> 4) * 4;
    
    int payload_length = pkthdr->caplen - (14 + ip_len + tcp_len);
    int total_headers_size = 14 + ip_len + tcp_len;
    payload = total_headers_size + packet;

    switch (ip->protocol) {
        case 6:
            switch (tls->Handshake__type) {
                case 22:
                    printf("packet[%d]", p_count);
                    compress_data(payload, payload_length);//calling compressing function
                    break;
            }
    }
    p_count++;
}

void compress_data(void* in_data, size_t payload_length) {

    const size_t BUFSIZE = 128 * 1024;
    uint8_t temp_buffer[BUFSIZE];
    uLong size[payload_length+1];
    uLong s = compressBound(temp_buffer);
    z_stream com_stream;
    com_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    com_stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    com_stream.opaque = Z_NULL;

    com_stream.avail_in = (uInt) payload_length;
    com_stream.next_in = (Bytef *) in_data;
    com_stream.avail_out = s;
    com_stream.next_out = (Bytef *) temp_buffer;

    while (com_stream.avail_in != 0) {

        deflateInit(&com_stream, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
        deflate(&com_stream, Z_FINISH);
        deflateEnd(&com_stream);

        printf("Uncompressed size is: %lu ||", com_stream.total_in);
        printf("Compressed size is: %lu ||", com_stream.total_out);

        float c_size = ((float) (com_stream.total_in - com_stream.total_out) / (float) com_stream.total_in) * 100;
        printf("compressed Percentage: %.2f%% \n", c_size);
        
    }
    
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char *device;
    pcap_t *handle;
    char error_buffer[100];

    handle = pcap_open_offline("packet.pcap", error_buffer);
    pcap_loop(handle, -1, callback, NULL);

}````

**output** :

packet[2729]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 384 ||compressed Percentage: 25.73% 
packet[2740]Uncompressed size is: 1360 ||Compressed size is: 1371 ||compressed Percentage: 1356378297306447872.00% 
packet[2741]packet[2755]Uncompressed size is: 4291 ||Compressed size is: 4302 ||compressed Percentage: 429893825096318976.00% 
packet[2756]packet[3462]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 393 ||compressed Percentage: 23.98% 
packet[3469]Uncompressed size is: 1360 ||Compressed size is: 1371 ||compressed Percentage: 1356378297306447872.00% 
packet[3470]packet[3521]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 378 ||compressed Percentage: 26.89% 
packet[3529]Uncompressed size is: 1360 ||Compressed size is: 1371 ||compressed Percentage: 1356378297306447872.00% 
packet[3530]packet[3836]Uncompressed size is: 659 ||Compressed size is: 670 ||compressed Percentage: 2799202397811900416.00% 
packet[3978]packet[4134]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 395 ||compressed Percentage: 23.60% 
packet[4136]Uncompressed size is: 2720 ||Compressed size is: 2731 ||compressed Percentage: 678189148653223936.00% 
packet[4137]packet[4155]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 405 ||compressed Percentage: 21.66% 
packet[4157]Uncompressed size is: 2720 ||Compressed size is: 2731 ||compressed Percentage: 678189148653223936.00% 
packet[4158]packet[4206]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 405 ||compressed Percentage: 21.66% 
packet[4208]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 406 ||compressed Percentage: 21.47% 
packet[4212]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 406 ||compressed Percentage: 21.47% 
packet[4216]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 406 ||compressed Percentage: 21.47% 
packet[4220]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 405 ||compressed Percentage: 21.66% 
packet[4224]Uncompressed size is: 517 ||Compressed size is: 406 ||compressed Percentage: 21.47% 
packet[4226]Uncompressed size is: 2720 ||Compressed size is: 2731 ||compressed Percentage: 678189148653223936.00%
`````

Comment: Not all data compresses.  Data that is already compressed (jpeg, zip, gunzip, etc.) generally doesn't compress any more.  Some algorithms might compress and abandon the compressed version if it doesn't save anything.

Comment: @stdunbar is it possible that large size payloads(2700 bytes)  compressed size gets larger or are there any algorithms I should try. I am trying to follow WAN optimization concept to  minimize bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

You results show an overhead of maximum 11 bytes. This matches the overhead of zlib in case of not compressible data. To cite from the official documentation about [Technical Details: Maximum Expansion Factor](https://zlib.net/zlib_tech.html):

> In the worst possible case, where the other block types would expand the data, deflation falls back to stored (uncompressed) blocks. Thus for the default settings used by deflateInit(), compress(), and compress2(), the only expansion is an **overhead of five bytes per 16 KB block** (about 0.03%), plus a **one-time overhead of six bytes** for the entire stream.

Thus, the compression behaves as expected.

What is wrong though is your calculation of the compression percentage which does not handle the case of output site greater than payload size. Instead it results in unsigned integer underflow - the conversation to float
Apart from the calculation of the float from unsigned integer must be done before subtracting output and input size.